# Possible conflict between `csquotes` and `lua-widow-control`

Tags: csquotes

My MWE is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{csquotes}
% \usepackage{lua-widow-control}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
\enquote{And has thou slain the Jabberwock?\\
Come to my arms, my beamish boy!\\
O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!}\\
He chortled in his joy.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

If the line `\usepackage{lua-widow-control}` is uncommented, and the file compiled with `lualatex`, I get the error:

> ! Package csquotes Error: Unbalanced groups or invalid nesting.
>
> See the csquotes package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.9 O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!}
>                                \\
> ```

I think there is some conflict between the `csquote` and `lua-widow-contrl` packages and would appreciate it if those best qualified to, do address it.

Comment: This is due to a bad interaction between csquotes and the microtype package (loaded by lua-widow-control), which has already been fixed in the [dev version](https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/tree/dev).

Answer (score 1):

[Robert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7674/robert) is correct, there is a conflict between `csquotes` and `microtype`. You can block `microtype` from loading with `\RemoveFromHook{begindocument/before}[lua-widow-control]`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lua-widow-control}
\RemoveFromHook{begindocument/before}[lua-widow-control]
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
\enquote{And has thou slain the Jabberwock?\\
Come to my arms, my beamish boy!\\
O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!}\\
He chortled in his joy.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

However, `lua-widow-control` tends to not work very well without `microtype`, so you should only prevent it from loading until the fixed `microtype` is released.

Comment: A less drastic workaround would be `\PassOptionsToPackage{nopatch=item}{microtype}` instead of removing microtype altogether.